# Обновление данных в БД на PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Друзья подскажите как быть!
Я с помощью Ajax  отправляю данные на сервер для добавления в БД, на сервере обычный код с UPDATE.

Не могу придумать универсальный код чтобы при различных запросах на обновление в одну и ту же таблицу не писать новый код.

Например если я обновляю только стоимость то это один UPDATE если обновляется стоимость и описание, то это уже другой, но вариантов может быть куча.

```
//обновление заказа в базе денных
    public function update_order($order, $pdo){

        $sql = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `orders` SET 
            `company` = :company, `order_name` = :order_name, `status` = :status, `dead_line` = :dead_line, `cost` = :cost, `payment` = :payment, `description` = :description, `bill` = :bill, `act` = :act, `contract` = :contract WHERE `id` = :id");
        $sql->execute([

            ':id' => $order['id'],
            ':company' => $order['company'],
            ':order_name' => $order['order_name'],
            ':status' => $order['status'],
            ':dead_line' => $order['dead_line'],
            ':cost' => $order['cost'],
            ':payment' => $order['payment'],
            ':description' => $order['description'],
            ':bill' => $order['bill'],
            ':act' => $order['act'],
            ':contract' => $order['contract']

        ]);
        return $order['dead_line'];
    }//end addOrder
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//обновление заказа в базе денных
public function update_order($order, $pdo){
    $query_list = [];
    $execute_list = ["id" => $order["id"]];
    $fields = ["company", "order_name", ];
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if (!empty($order[$field]) {
            $query_list[] = "`$field` = :$field";
            $execute_list[":$field"] = $order[$field];
        }
    }

    $sql = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `orders` SET " . implode(", ", $query_list) . " WHERE `id` = :id");
    $sql->execute(execute_list);
    return $order['dead_line'];
}//end addOrder
```

Comment: Спасибо. Вопрос решен.